# styled-components makes input range not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

```
  const Input = styled.input`
    display: block;
  `;

  const [slider, setSlider] = useState(25);

  const onSlide = (e) => {
    setSlider(e.target.value);
  };
```

When I return

`<input type="range" name="slider" min="1" max="60" value={slider} onChange={onSlide}/>`

It works

`<Input type="range" name="slider" min="1" max="60" value={slider} onChange={onSlide}/>`

The slider does not slide anymore I don't understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You've probably defined the styled `Input` within your render function. It should be defined externally.

[Define Styled Components outside of the render method](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#define-styled-components-outside-of-the-render-method)

> It is important to define your styled components outside of the render
> method, otherwise it will be recreated on every single render pass.
> Defining a styled component within the render method will thwart
> caching and drastically slow down rendering speed, and should be
> avoided.

## Solution

Define `Input` outside of any render function.

**Remember**, the *entire* body of a functional component is the *render function*.

```
const Input = styled.input`
  display: block;
`;

function App() {
  const [slider, setSlider] = useState(25);

  const onSlide = (e) => {
    setSlider(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      ...

      <Input
        type="range"
        name="slider"
        min="1"
        max="60"
        value={slider}
        onChange={onSlide}
      />

      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit styled-components-makes-input-range-not-work]

Comment: Thank you, it was because my styled-component was inside the functional component rather than outside

Answer (score 0):

I made a sandbox with the code below and it works. I gave input a classname called slider.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Styles = styled.div`

  .slider { 
    display: block;
  }
`;

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(100);

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setState(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Styles>
      <input
        type="range"
        min={0}
        max={255}
        value={state}
        className="slider"
        onChange={handleOnChange}
      />
      <div className="value">{state}</div>
    </Styles>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you, it was because my styled-component was inside the functional component rather than outside